# How to set the height of the Sublime Text 2 status bar, or get its history?

Tags: sublimetext2

I'm currently using the [Sublime Code Intel](https://github.com/Kronuz/SublimeCodeIntel) plugin with ST2. Trying to add additional python paths but it's not working. So I'm trying to do a little debug and notice that the plugin prints the paths being searched in the ST2 status bar as it's building the index. The problem is, a lot of the messages go by too fast. I've just started using this editor and so far I can't find out how to either expand the height of the status bar - so I could scroll up a few commands - or view some  sort of status bar history. As it is, I can only see the last thing logged in the status bar and that's not very useful for debugging my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The [console](https://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/basic_concepts.html?highlight=console#the-python-console-and-the-python-api) provides useful debug info.  You can also use it to enter Python commands.

To open: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>

or

`View>Show Console`

Comment: Thanks. I know about the console and it is very useful for seeing errors logged by some plugins. However not every thing written to the status bar is necessarily available in the console. So, it doesn't really answer my question.